# How to disable the line space settings of footnote texts in the setspace package?

Tags: setspace

First a MWS and its output are as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{musicography}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see the line spacings of footnote texts are different of those of main texts. This is because the `musicography` package invokes the `setspace` package implicitly. Is there any way to load the `musicography` package (in which some symbols are necessary) but disable the line space settings of footnote texts in the `setspace` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not seem there is an option to disable the adjustment for the footnotes. But you can patch it away

```
\usepackage{musicography,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@footnotetext{%
  \def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}%
}{}{\typeout{patched}}{\typeout{not patched}}
\makeatother
```